Why does $\sum_{k=1}^n {r \choose k} \leq r^n$ hold?
This wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning#Number_of_components
defines a function $Comp(n,r)$ that counts the number of partitions of an Euclidian $n$-dimensional space by $r$ hyperplanes. And asserts that
$$Comp(n,r) =
\begin{cases}
\sum_{k=0}^n {r \choose k} & \text{if } r > n \\
2^r & \text{if } r \leq n
\end{cases}
$$
and that this verifies
$Comp(n,r) \leq r^n + 1$
When either $n=0$ or $r=0$ it's easy to see that the bound holds.
For $r = 1, n \geq 1$, $Comp(n,1)= Comp(n,0) + Comp(n-1, 0) = 2 = 1^n+1$
And if $2 \leq r \leq n$, then $2^r \leq 2^n \leq r^n$.
So all that's left is to show that the bound holds for $r>n$. In this case, the bound is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n {r \choose k} \leq r^n
$$
And this is where I'm stuck. Most reasonable attempt so far was defining
$$
 f(x) = x^n - \sum_{k=1}^n p_k(x)
\qquad \text{ with } \ 
p_k(x) = \frac{1}{k!} \prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(x-i)
$$
And trying to show that $f(x) \geq 0$ for $x \geq n$.

You can try calculating $f(x + 1) - f(x)$. This will let you prove the desired result by induction on $n$.

A combinatorial proof: consider $S = \{1,2,3, \ldots, r\}$, the set of integers between $1$ and $r$ inclusive.
The RHS $r^n$ is the number of sequences of length $n$ with elements from $S$.
The LHS $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom rk$ is the number of subsets of $S$ with size $k$, where $1 \le k\le n$.
Define an injection from such subsets to non-decreasing sequences of length $n$. The injection maps a subset of size $k$ to the sequence:

terms $1$ to $k$ are the distinct elements from the subset, in ascending order; and
terms $k+1$ to $n$, if any, all repeat the maximum element from the subset.

The number of non-decreasing sequences of length $n$ is at most the number of all sequences of length $n$, hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom rk \le \binom{n+r-1}{n} \le r^n$$
(the middle $\binom{n+r-1}{n}$ is the number of all non-decreasing sequences of length $n$.)

Algebraically based on such combinatorial proof,
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n \binom rk
&\le \sum_{k=1}^n \binom rk \binom{n-1}{n-k}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom rk \binom{n-1}{n-k}\\
&= \binom{r+n-1}{n} &&\text{(Vandermonde's identity)}\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^n\frac{r+k-1}{k}\\
&\le \prod_{k=1}^n\frac{r+(k-1)r}{k}\\
&= r^n\\
\end{align*}$$

I am ok with the injection ${ \text{ subsets of } S \text{ of length } k } \to S^n $.
But I don't see why $ \sum_{k=1}^n {r \choose k} \leq { {n+r-1} \choose n } $

@nsmon93 The proposed injection above maps subsets of size $1\le k\le n$ to non-decreasing sequences of length $n$, and the $\binom{n+r-1}n$ is the number of all non-decreasing sequences of length $n$.

Nice answer.. +1
